# Spring webflow: How to configure Multiple Flow Executors

Tags: spring-webflow-2

I am trying to configure multiple flow executors for my project as I need one set of flows with 'always-redirect-on-pause' attribute as false and another as true. I have tried searching, skimming Spring Docs but been unable to come up with this configuration. Can anyone please share these configurations and/or direct to some relevant resource?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple workflow (flow definition files) location registration in your project Spring Configuration file

**Spring Configuration**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd">

    <bean id="assetManagementService" />

    <bean id="savingsAssetService" />

    <bean id="handlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>/assetMgmtHomeView.htm=flowController</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="flowController">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
    </webflow:flow-executor>

    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry">
        <webflow:flow-location id="assetMgmtHomeView" path="/WEB-INF/flows/assetMgmtFlow.xml" />
        <webflow:flow-location id="savingsAssetViewFlow" path="/WEB-INF/flows/savingsAssetViewFlow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>

</beans>
```

As you can see `webflow:flow-registry` contains two workflow xml files path. Keep in mind that those location registrations have different **IDs** used to distinguish among the workflows.

Comment: do you not need to map `/savingsAssetViewFlow.htm` to `flowController` also? I ask mostly because I'm trying to learn this stuff too.